# subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE и виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, venv

При запуске такого модуля:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('python client.py', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Новое окно открывается от основного интерпретатора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя виртуальное окружение активировано и находится по другому пути.

Или так и должно быть?

Если что, весь код учебный.

Comment: Ну, путь еще ни о чем не говорит. Внутри окружения лежит не копия интерпретатора, а пусковой файл (py.exe переименованный в python.exe). Под *nix подобными системами - вообще просто ссылка на исходный интерпретатор. Если все работает, и видит установленные в окружение зависимости, значит все ок.